# How can I uninstall an old version of OpenSSL while keeping CrowdStrike working with the new version installed?

Tags: openssl, version

Dealing w/ an issue with upgrading OpenSSL on Centos 7. When running yum update openssl it does not upgrade the current version of OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017. It says that's the latest version installed. I did try other googling other repos to see if that would of helped but did not have any luck.

I was able to install OpenSSL version 1.1.1v using this article: https://blacksaildivision.com/how-to-install-openssl-on-centos

Now the issue is removing the old version without breaking CrowdStrike falcon-sensor. If I try to do a yum remove openssl, it warns me it will remove CrowdStrike as well.

Has anyone dealt lth w/ this issue before and found a way to remove the old version of OpenSSL while keeping CrowdStrike working w/ the new version installed?

1. Tried updating the repo file to point to other sites
2. Removed yum openssl and then try to install crowdstrike again